# How to delete duplicate row when importing data from Excel to SQL Server 2008

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I would like to import Excel data into a SQL Server table. My Excel data may be duplicate to the data already in the SQL Server table.

My table does not have primary key. When importing Excel data into SQL Server, I would like to delete duplicate record in SQL Server table before inserting Excel 
data.

I use the `Database>> Tasks >> Import Data` functionality to do the import. This option allow to import duplicate data without delete. How can I delete duplicate rows when importing data from Excel into SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel Macro to delete those duplicate rows.

Copy code below into your excel macro module and run it.

Note: Change all "A1" to string refer to first cell of your key column.
Should not have space or blank row between all data row because code will stop if it found blank cell.

```
Sub deleteDuplicateRow()
Dim i As Long

i = 0
Do While Range("A1").Offset(i).Value <> ""
    If Range("A1").Offset(i).Value = Range("A1").Offset(i + 1).Value Then
        Range("A1").Offset(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```